# Can Deferred.pipe() prevent call of both subsequent .done and .fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have two handlers: onSuccess and onFailure, but I want sometimes (when the server decides so), to prevent either of them from running. I know I can return some 'ignore' from the `.pipe()` and to test for it within the `.done()` and `.fail()` handlers, but is there more elegant way, like tweak something in the `this` inside the `.pipe()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide more details of your case ?

When does `onFailure` should be called or not ? If your server call fails, how could you be able to know if you need to call something or nothing as you ask ?

If I understand what you ask, you want to avoid to have a "if" statement in all your methods `onSuccess` and `onFailure`. A way to do that could be to add an intermediate `.pipe` call and returning a new promise depending on your server answer to do something or not.

Comment: do you mean return `$.Deferred()` in `.pipe()` ? like: `def.pipe(...){ if (break_the_chain) return $.Deferred(); }` ?

Comment: Yes, something like that. The problem with this solution is if your server call fails, you can't switch server answer, or do it in the "fail" of your first deferred. I need more information about your "switch" conditions or server call to give you better code example.

Comment: That's my current solution - return `$.Deferred()` and do nothing with it. Hope there's no memory leak or something (since these returned deferred are never resolved/rejected..)